# How can I detect the screen being folded back on a Lenovo Yoga C930?

Tags: laptop, lenovo, input-devices

I have a Lenovo Yoga C930, a laptop whose lid can be folded all the way to the back to convert into a tablet. I know that Ubuntu is able to in some way detect this event, because it turns the keyboard off when I do this, and turns it back on when I unfold the screen again.

How can I detect this myself, so as to run a script every time it happens?

[This](https://github.com/alesguzik/linux_detect_tablet_mode) tool solves this problem using libinput, but apparently this doesn't work for the C930 because when I run `libinput debug-events` and fold back the screen, nothing is logged. Nothing shows up in dmesg either, other than the possibly relevant message `[120532.207160] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 10` when I *unfold* the screen.

Comment: Try to run "journalctl" in a terminal and use 'ctrl' 'end' to see the latest entries in the system log. That might give you a hint.

Comment: @minimec Tried that also... same results as dmesg.

Comment: Try using `udev` and monitor events: `udevadm monitor`. Then you can also write a `udev`-rule to trigger a command upon a certain action.

Comment: @Fiximan Nothing there either I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, become `root` (`sudo su`) and use `watch -d journalctl -e ` to see what events are triggered when folding/unfolding. If they are not even system events, how should they change anything?

Comment: @Fiximan I've tried `dmesg`, `journalctl -f`, and `udevadm monitor` - all as root, and they all give similar results. No logs that correlate with folding/unfolding the screen, other than the aforementioned "Unknown event" message from `ideapad_laptop`, which as I said only occurs when *un*folding.

Comment: Hmm, I just had some luck with `acpi_listen`. I get some output there when I fold and unfold the screen... although oddly, I get exactly the same message whether I'm folding or unfolding: `06129D99-6083- 000000d0 00000000`

Comment: @JackM Any updates? Seeing the same on Yoga 13w.

Comment: @JackM Apparently, key-presses for KEY_F23 and KEY_F22 `libinput` events are generated on folding/unfolding, respectively.